# locating related posts by tag list

Tags: php, sql, algorithm

I have a table containing news posts, one of the fields in this table is a 'tags' field, which contains a list of comma delimited tags - Why that is the case is irrelevant, as this is a legacy table and tags cannot now be ported out to another table, and no changes may be made to the table structure or the app's functionality.

I am trying to determine the best way to query the database to find posts with similar tags.

Does anyone have a better/smarter solution than splitting and trimming the tag field and performing a LIKE query?

Comment: better/smarter solution for a not so smarter database design?

Comment: i agree completely, but since it's out of my hands, there's not much i can do, i need to solve a legacy issue, i'll curse the db designer later :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't touch the DB, can you add an additional search index external to the DB, e.g. Lucene or Sphinx?

If we are not talking about potentially large amounts of data, you can even use Zend_Search_Lucene from ZF to implement a Lucene index without any external service / software installs etc.

Then, you can index posts by tag, use the index to find posts with a certain tag (or combination of tags and other properties), and fetch the relevant results from the DB based on their ID returned from Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `tags` table, and a many to many `tags_posts` table between `tags` and `posts` tables.

Then, you could migrate the `posts.tags` column into `tags` and and `tags_posts`.

Finally, you'd be able to query `tags_posts` rather than `posts.tags`.

Comment: that is exactly the solution i'm trying to avoid, as i will need to update major parts of the application as well. leaving things as they are in the database is, sadly, a requirement.

Comment: What about a cron job that updates tags_posts and tags based on posts.tags ? You'd keep posts.tags - until you update your whole application - and be able to use tags_posts right away.

Comment: that is a slightly better option than porting the entire thing, but the duplicity is kind-of off-putting, don't you think?

Comment: There's always "kind-of off-putting" when you want to upgrade a software **partially** because that requires **backward compatibility**. Why do you think so many things are insane in PHP itself hehe

Answer (score 0):

Moving to sphinx/lucene architecture involves some work to do, which gonna be harder then just moving the tags out to a separate table.
The simpliest solution, rather then fetching all and parsing all the strings, you could run a search similar to `WHERE instr(concat(",", tags_field,","), ',php,') > 0`